# How can I set an Azure Logic App's Authentication Policy in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps

I am working on getting all components of my Azure architecture managed by Terraform using the template json method.

However, I cannot properly define the route to the Logic App created by Terraform, due to an authentication policy that is not setup/listed in the Logic App's template.

Looking through Hashicorp's documentation, I'm not seeing any particular resource or attribute that I can use to manage this Authentication policy with Terraform.

Has anyone managed this or am I looking at something that Hashicorp hasnt caught up to managing with Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Logic App resource JSON, under `properties.accessControl.triggers.openAuthenticationPolicies.policies` you should be able to see your policy. Use this to set access control, for example:

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
  ...

  access_control {
    trigger {
      allowed_caller_ip_address_range = ["*"]

      open_authentication_policy {
        name = "ad-auth"

        claim {
          name  = "iss"
          value = "https://sts.windows.net/${data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id}/"
        }

        claim {
          name  = "aud"
          value = tolist(azuread_application.example.identifier_uris)[0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note `allowed_caller_ip_address_range` parameter is required.

Don't forget to set up OAuth for your triggers: read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#enable-azure-active-directory-open-authentication-azure-ad-oauth)

Comment: The solution does not work for me. The script fails because of an invalid ip range. When try to add something else, the policy is never created. Any idea ?

Comment: @RomEh Try an IP range of `["0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255"]`: this works for me

Comment: I finally found the solution. I was deploying the Logic App first with the Terraform azurerm_logic_app_workflow object, and the with the ARM template for the content. The Logic App ARM template deployement erase the access control configured in Terraform, and must be set in the ARM template. Thanks for the answer @Epic Wink

Answer (score -1):

Based on the Hashicrop documentation,there is no authentication policy for the logic apps in terraform . below are the list of methods that terraform support for [authenticating for  azure resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/managed_service_identity)

- Authenticating to Azure using the Azure CLI
- Authenticating to Azure using Managed Identity
- Authenticating to Azure using a Service Principal and a Client Certificate
- Authenticating to Azure using a Service Principal and a Client Secret

Here is the reference SO thread for creating a logic app creation with managed identity using terraform in arm template deployment

[Assign an Azure Logic Apps Managed Identity a role with terraform via ARM Deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429421/assign-an-azure-logic-apps-managed-identity-a-role-with-terraform-via-arm-deploy)